# takin null all the time PHP

Tags: php, android

I am really beginner on PHP and Android and I can't find the problem.

Here is the by return book PHP code.

Firstly it takes two variables `Id` and `id`. It selects `id` from `Books` database if the `id` matches it store the Books database variables.

If `takenby === Id` it should assign `true` to `$success`, otherwise it should assign `false` to `$success` but every time `$success` is `null`.

I don't understand why it is always `null`.

Thank for your answering...

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localHost","name","password","database");


    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $Id = $_POST["Id"];


    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

    $statement2 = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement2,"s" , $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement2);



    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement2);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement2, $name, $author, $ıd, $date, $takenby);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;








    if($takenby===$Id)
    {

        $statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE Books SET takenby = '' , date = '' WHERE id = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"s" , $id);
        $success = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    }


    $response = array();
    $response["success"]=$success;
    $response["id"] = $id;





     //json data formatı
    echo json_encode($response);

    mysqli_close($con);


    ?>
```

Here is the console output,

> Value `null` at `success` of type `org.json.JSONObject$1` cannot be converted to `boolean`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that php script. But the things you mentioned in the subject are not mentioned in your post. Please rethink and rephrase.

Comment: Well if the php is ok. Then what is wrong?

Comment: it should return true or false not null

Comment: No not at all. That script returns a json text. The script looks ok. The problem is somewhere else. Now rephrase your post as it has nothing to do with your subject.

Comment: 'Here is the console output Value null at success of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to boolean'. Whete is that console? And which code isvinvolved?

Comment: Android logcat gives this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in that script is missing the fetch part. After I realized that fetch is missing, and I fetch statement.

Here is some example from PHP documentation about fetch

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?> [1]
```

If someone encounters some kind of problem, ı hope that it would help.
[1] http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php